# Conditionally delete SQL rows

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

Using Linq 2 SQL CE on Windows Phone 7.1, how can I trigger "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column=some_value" SQL command?

Unfortunately, erasing items with Table.DeleteAllOnSubmit() method is unacceptably slow even after increasing "max buffer size" parameter to 1024: stupud Linq deserializes each record, so the DataContext.SubmitChanges() method never returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot trigger the desired DELETE statement, but you can do:

Use .Take(100) to only fetech and delete a set of records per SubmitChanges() call, and run in a loop until you get no more rows returned.

Use a rowversion column to speed up deletes, from 320 ms to under 70 ms in my test - see http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/04/windows-phone-local-database-tip.html

Comment: Unfortunately I have a secondary index covering primary index column. I would remove it, however the Microsoft's DatabaseSchemaUpdater has no API to delete an index from my table :-(

Comment: But you can still use Take.. !?

Comment: The Take() slowed down the deletion by ~9%, here're the figures: All at once: 2033 entries in 97 seconds, 1214 entries in 58 seconds
By taking 128 records: 2033 entries in 105 seconds, 1214 entries in 64.7 seconds

Comment: 2033 entries in 14 seconds, 1208 entries in 3.98 seconds - much better :-) Thanks a lot! BTW, for upgrading schema I've just renamed the DB file.